# I want to create a discount calculator in C, using a function. I want to get the values from user. But mine is not working

Tags: c

Here is the code. The function **getDiscountedPrice** will give me an amount of the money I am getting as a cashback discount. Suppose, I have bought a Mobile, it costs 2000 USD, the amount of discount is 15%. So I will get `(15/100*2000) = 300` USD discount so that the mobile will cost me 1700 USD.

So, I want the total price value and the percentage to take from the user and use it inside my function. So, what can I do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
float getDiscountedPrice(float totalPrice, float discountedPercent){
    float percentageOf = discountedPercent/100*totalPrice;
    return totalPrice - percentageOf;
}

int main(){
    float totalPrice, discountedPercent, sum;
    printf("Total price of the product? - ");
    scanf("%d", &totalPrice);
    printf("The amount of discount percentage? - ");
    scanf("%d", &discountedPercent);
    sum = getDiscountedPrice(totalPrice,discountedPercent);
    printf("Your discounted price is Rs%f", sum);

}
```

Comment: If you ask a question in the future, please help others to help you. Although Abhishek appears to have spotted the problem, just saying "_But mine is not working_" is not usually very helpful. Did the program refuse to compile? Terminate unexpectedly? Produce an error message? Calculate the wrong answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `%d` as the format specifier when the data-type is float. Just change it to `%f` and your program should work fine.

Corrected code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
float getDiscountedPrice(float totalPrice, float discountedPercent){
    float percentageOf = (discountedPercent/100)*totalPrice;
    return totalPrice - percentageOf;
}

int main(){
    float totalPrice, discountedPercent, sum;
    printf("Total price of the product? - ");
    scanf("%f", &totalPrice);
    printf("The amount of discount percentage? - ");
    scanf("%f", &discountedPercent);
    sum = getDiscountedPrice(totalPrice,discountedPercent);
    printf("Your discounted price is Rs %f", sum);

}
```